# Comparing double for equality is not safe. So what to do if want to compare it to 0?

Tags: java, double

I know that because of binary double representation, comparison for equality of two `double`s is not quite safe. But I need to perform some computation like this:

```
double a;
//initializing
if(a != 0){       // <----------- HERE
    double b = 2 / a;
   //do other computation
}
throw new RuntimeException();
```

So, comparison of `double`s is not safe, but I definitely do not want to to devide by 0. What to do in this case?

I'd use `BigDecimal` but its performance is not quite acceptable.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114498/can-a-near-zero-floating-value-cause-a-divide-by-zero-error/12115243#12115243

Comment: Dividing by zero is often a surprisingly reasonable thing to do with doubles.

Comment: try catch the divide by zero exception

Comment: If `a` is a method variable or parameter, or it is declared `final` or `volatile`, it will be thread-safe.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I don't think that's the question

Comment: when checking if a floating point value like double or float is 0, an error threshold is used to detect if the value is near 0, but not quite 0.

public boolean checkZero(double value, double threshold){
    return value >= -threshold && value <= threshold;
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if your issue is dividing by zero, the good news is that you can do what you have since if the value isn't actually 0, you can divide by it, even if it's really, really small.

You can use a range comparison, comparing it to the lowest value you want to allow, e.g. `a >= 0.0000000000001` or similar (if it's always going to be positive).

Comment: Actually, in this particular case very very small values do not cause DevisionByZero-related `Exception`, and it's safe. Thank you.

Comment: Not even dividing by zero causes an exception in double arithmetic; it just returns a (valid) infinite result.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I thought that too, thanks for confirming. I wasn't sure enough of my facts (my Java is rusty) to say it in an answer I was about to leave unattended, even after reading [*Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed infinity. The sign is determined by the rule stated above.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2).

Answer (score 0):

What about using the Static method compare of the Double class wrapper??

```
double a = 0.0;
// initializing
if (Double.compare(a, 0.0) != 0) {

}
```

Comment: hm... but is it actually different from the original example?

Comment: This provides no benefit over a regular `== 0` comparison.

Comment: yes... you delegate the comparing operation to the class Double... so how its done is none of your bussines anymore....

Comment: It still is your problem if the method doesn't do what you semantically require. Calling a method doesn't absolve you of the duty to ensure code correctness.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpa: That's like saying that shooting people is bad, so you're going to delegate to a hitman and how it's done is none of your business any more. The problems with exact comparisons to 0 don't go away just because they're hidden behind an abstraction layer.